# Turning off social apps

Tags: mobile-data

I would like to know if there is a way in Android 6.0.1 to turn off certain apps when I am using mobile data. For example, I would like to turn off Facebook Messenger while keeping Whatsapp available. Is that possible? I have a friend that can do this but I cannot do it in my phone.
Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Install a firewall and restrict internet access to your desired app. 
You can grant access to mobile data or WiFi or block completely from accessing data.
There is an inbuilt app in Lenovo handsets called security, which does this job pretty well.

[image: Lenovo security firewall]
<sup>Lenovo security firewall (click image for larger variant)</sup>

Comment: For those devices where such a Firewall is not integrated (99% of all devices, I'm afraid), there are third-party-apps, not all of them requiring root. You can find a selection in [my corresponding app list](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_admin_firewall#group_377). Most recommended choice: AFWall+ (requires root). From the no-root fraction, NetGuard was long time recommended (I don't know if it still is – but that would be a case for [our sister site](//android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2060/16575) :).